# ArcMap ignoring TiledLabelsToAnnotation in ArcPy script?

Tags: arcpy, python, arcmap

I'd write python script that execute TiledLabelsToAnnotation_cartography tool.
This script is call by a tbx file.

No problem when i launch my python script in Visual Studio Code, result is correct.
Now, i need to valid my script in ArcMap to share my geoprocessing as web service .sd file (arcgis server). 
But arcmap ignore TiledLabelsToAnnotation_cartography tool and break my script... So, layers generated by this function missing and i have failed execution because i need this layers to realize a clip.

> /!\  Failed to execute. Parameters are
>   not valid. ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset
>   C:\Users...\scratch.gdb\LAYER_XXX_SEP150
>   does not exist or is not supported

Already try :

- realize TiledLabelsToAnnotation_cartography execution with python geoprocessing window with same parameters =  excecution success.
- Manually import missing layers in gdb = execution success.

Why arcmap ignore this function ?

Code :

```
\# Entry : MXD_ETQ contain labels layers 
MXD_ETQ = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(path)

\#copy MXD to preserve original MXD from additionnal annotation layers
MXD_copy_path  = os.path.join(temp_folder, "_labels")
MXD_ETQ.saveACopy(MXD_copy_path)

\#tiled labels to annotation ---> Ignored by ArcMap
arcpy.TiledLabelsToAnnotation_cartography(
        MXD_copy_path, df_name , EXTENT_LAYER , TEMP_GDB , "ETQ", "SEP", 150, 
        "", "", "", "", "STANDARD", "NOT_GENERATE_UNPLACED_ANNOTATION")
```

Comment: Can you present a code snippet that we can use to try and reproduce this, please?

Comment: i can't write all the code, just concern part.